# custom attributes version of accepts_nested_attributes_for with reject_if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to create a custom version of this below

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories, :reject_if => proc { |hash| hash['title'].blank? }
```

So far what i got is

```
  def categories_attributes=(categories_attributes)
    categories_attributes.values.each do |category_attribute|
      category = Category.find_or_create_by(category_attribute)
      categories << category
    end
  end
```

But i am trying to add the reject_if part to it, i cant seem to figure it out. how can i replicate that portion into my custom attribute below?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do as this way

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories, reject_if: :title_blank

def title_blank(attributed)
  data = false
  data = true if attributed.title.blank?
  return data
end
```

Comment: I am trying to use a custom attribute not the accepts_nested_attributes_for thats included with rails

Comment: The version of accepts_nested_attributes_for i posted works, im trying to replicate it into a custom version